# Why doesn't a value inside a function update on each individual call?

Tags: javascript

```
function a(delay){

    this.randomVal = Math.random();

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        document.write('function a called - '+this.randomVal+' '+delay+'<br/>');
    }, delay)


}


a(2000);
a(5000);
a(1000);
```

Resulting output:

```
function a called - 0.7679888338316232 1000
function a called - 0.7679888338316232 2000
function a called - 0.7679888338316232 5000
```

I'm sure this is a classic problem, but why doesn't the randomVal inside function 'a' update every time it is called..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because all the callback functions have a reference to the **same variable**, `this.randomVal`, which is a property of the global object (`window`) (`this` refers to `window` in your case).

So your code is basically the same as:

```
function a(delay){

    randomVal = Math.random();
    // ...
}
```

By the time the first callback function is called, you already called `a` the third time, so all callback functions access the value of `this.randomVal` which was set in the last call.

This can be easily solved by using `var` instead if `this`, thus making it a *local variable* instead of a *global* one:

```
function a(delay){
    var randomVal = Math.random();
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        document.write('function a called - ' + randomVal + ' ' + delay + '<br/>');
    }, delay)
}
```

*(And please don't use `document.write`)*.

Answer (score 3):

Because the expression `document.write('function a called - '+this.randomVal+' '+delay+'<br/>');` is executed "later", then the value of `this.randomVal` is the latest value generated by `this.randomVal = Math.random();`

You can fix this behavior by creating a closure:

```
function a(delay){

    var randomVal = Math.random();

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        document.write('function a called - '+randomVal+' '+delay+'<br/>');
    }, delay)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It *does* get updated, *right when the function is called.* But the value isn't printed till after the delay. The first printout occurs long after the third actual call to a(), so it's the third update of the member variable that's displayed by all three calls. Fershtay?

If you want it to print three separate values, then don't use a property of that object to hold the value -- just keep it in a variable local to that function.